# Can I add new attribute to an existing table in Laravel Dynamically?

Tags: mysql, json, database, laravel, api

I am building Dashboard in Laravel with API to Mobile Application.
In the mobile app there is a container that has a Drop Down list connecting to the API to get `Department`.

When we choose one of the `Department` another Drop Down list appear contain `Department` info.
The problem some `Department` need to show another Drop Down list to choose. For example (the manufacture company) but some `Department` don't need that.

How can I deal with this problem in database? Is there any way to store this in my database without having `null` record.
If there is a way how I can send the data in API to mobile app to read the attribute that need to fill?

Comment: You could store that information in another table and use a relationship, however, that results in an additional `join`. What's your objection to a `null` value?

Comment: i know that solution but what if some department need only 1 Drop Down List , and some Department need 4 Drop Down list , is not make any seance to add new table every Time i need To Add new info

Comment: Then calling the relationship will result in an empty response in which case you don't render an additional list. You don't add a new table every time, you add a new record to the table for the required information.

Comment: Is there a way to add a new field through the code without go to mysql and add it manully